# NAS ip's showing up twice (DUP) and NAS not accessible

Tags: networking, 16.04, nas, mediaserver

we have two NAS backup servers here for holiday photo and video and such things... both are `fujitsu NAS`. One is a Q800 and one is a newer Q802 series.

We have actually the problem that the Q802 shows up fine and is accessible by the web-admin panel but the older Q800 makes some trouble.

In general its detected on the local network (see below the arp scan result but its not accessible by the admin web panel or by connection from any kind of ubuntu station. I also recognized that for some reason the older Q800 have some double network entry:

```
sudo arp-scan --localnet
Interface: eth0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
192.168.192.1   (Unknown)
192.168.192.2   (Unknown)
192.168.192.20  ICP Electronics Inc.          #this is the Q802 which works fine
192.168.192.21  ICP Electronics Inc.          #this is the Q802 which works fine
192.168.192.62  ICP Electronics Inc.          #this is the Q800
192.168.192.62  ICP Electronics Inc. (DUP: 2) #this is the Q800
192.168.192.63  ICP Electronics Inc.          #this is the Q800
192.168.192.63  ICP Electronics Inc. (DUP: 2) #this is the Q800
192.168.192.46  (Unknown)

9 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.8.1: 256 hosts scanned in 3.200 seconds (80.00 hosts/sec). 9 responded
```

I also upped two pictures from within the same browser where the Q802 shows up and the Q800 doesn't.

[image: Q802 working webpanel]

[image: Q800 webpanel not responding]

Any ideas what this might cause? 
I can only assume but my guess is that the dupped IP's are making trouble and rejecting access to the web-admin panel?

Is there any further info I might share here to help find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have both network cards connected on Q800 ? If you do try to disconnect one network card and see if it works.

This NAS has load balancing options for network so it is possible that you enabled load balancing on NAS. You have to configure LACP on your switch before it will work.

Other option is that both cards have configured same ip address which leads to duplicate ip problems.

Comment: Thanks for the help ill try that. Indeed i have both ethernet cards connected. Ill report back

Comment: Okay im back in front of my pc. I just disconnected one of the ethernet cables and rebooted. The result is the same. Ill check the IP settings now

Comment: What i can see in the TCP/IP Settings is that the PRI DNS and SEC DNS are different on both NAS Servers:

Q802: 
PRI DNS: 192.168.192.1
SEC DNS: net

Q800:
PRI DNS: 0.0.0.0
SEC DNS: 0.0.0.0

But im not able to change those settings from in front of the NAS. As as you know im also not able to access the NAS from my ubuntu station if this should be the cultpriest how could i change those settings?

Comment: I think that DNS settings are not relevant. Have you tried to access to NAS on both ip adresses 192.168.192.62 and 192.168.192.63 ? Does ping 192.168.192.62 and ping 192.168.192.63 works ?

Comment: I disconnected the one card for now, so x.x.x.62 is the only reachable ip on local network. However pinging the x.x.x.62 works 

`ping 192.168.192.62
PING 192.168.192.62 (192.168.192.62) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.192.62: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.400 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.192.62: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.380 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.192.62: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.371 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.192.62: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.399 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.192.62: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.278 ms
[1]+  Stopped                 ping 192.168.192.62`

Comment: Ok now try open  port with 

telnet 192.168.192.62 8080. 

Output should be similar to 
Trying 192.168.192.62...
Connected to 192.168.192.62.
Escape character is '^]'.

If this works try different browser - not firefox.

Comment: Okay telenet seems not to work. telnet 192.168.192.62 8080
Trying 192.168.192.62...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out

Comment: Im thinking of reseting the NAS to let the router assign a new ip and force dhcp

Comment: Ok, there is one thing you can try as well. What does this command output - nmap 192.168.117.62. This will show open ports on your NAS.

Comment: I have reset the NAS to factory defaults. Everything works now like expected. Thanks to iuuuuan for your help!! Much appreciated!!